# How to use local resolutions in yarn workspaces?

Tags: javascript, yarnpkg, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

I have a monorepo based on yarn workspaces, with two projects, A and B. Both projects depend on the `foo` package.
I would like to create a resolution in the parent `package.json` file (since resolutions don't work on local `package.json` files in yarn workspaces) so that I can reference a different version of `foo` for each package.

Is it possible?

I have tried using something like this with no luck:

```js
"resolutions": {
  "A/foo": "1.0.0",
  "B/foo": "2.0.0"
}
```

**Important**: This is a simplified example, I know it should be as simple as using different versions of `foo` in each workspace. The real use case is more complex and involves a dependency chain I cannot alter :(